# Representing Fibonacci numbers using a list comprehension in Haskell

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension, fibonacci

I have written the following code to generate a list containing the Fibonacci numbers.

```
fibonacci = [a + b | a <- 1:fibonacci, b <- 0:1:fibonacci]
```

I would expect the output of the list to be `[1,2,3,5,8,13..]`, however, the output is not the Fibonacci sequence.

I can't quite understand why it doesn't work.

My reasoning is that, if the Fibonacci numbers are `[1,2,3,5,8,13..]` then this will be equal to the sum of the 2 lists `[1,1,2,3,5,8,13..]` and `[0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13..]`, which are equivalent to `1:[1,2,3,5,8,13..]` and `0:1:[1,2,3,5,8,13..]` or `1:fibonacci` and `0:1:fibonacci`

I have looked up other ways of implementing this sequence, however I would really like to know why my code doesn't work.

Comment: `fibonacci = 0:1:[a + b | (a:b:_) <- iterate tail fibonacci] = 0:1:[a + b | (a,b) <- zip fibonacci (tail fibonacci)]`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### The problem

With:

```
fibonacci = [a + b | a <- 1:fibonacci, b <- 0:1:fibonacci]
```

you are generating every possible combinations of the two lists. For example with:

```
x = [a + b | a <- [1, 2], b <- [3, 4]]
```

the result will be:

```
[1 + 3, 1 + 4, 2 + 3, 2 + 4]
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/087bf8bc4c2e1d2b)

### With `zipWith`

The closest you can get is with `zipWith`:

```
fibonacci :: [Int]
fibonacci = zipWith (+) (1:fibonacci) (0:1:fibonacci)
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3c8ba3a7c05ca481)

Comment: Of course! Thank you. I'll accept the answer as soon as I can.

Answer (score 8):

List comprehensions model

- Non-determinism
- Cartesian products
- Nested `for`-loops

which are all equivalent. So your Fibonacci sequence is wrong because it's computing way too many elements. In pseudocode it's a bit like

```
fibonacci = 
  for i in 1:fibonacci:
    for j in 0:1:fibonacci:
      i + j
```

What you really want is to zip the lists together, to perform computations in the order of the length of fibonacci instead of its square. To do that we can use `zipWith` and, with a little algebra, get the standard "tricky fibo"

```
fibonacci = zipWith (+) (1:fibonacci) (0:1:fibonacci)
fibonacci = zipWith (+) (0:1:fibonacci) (1:fibonacci)          -- (+) is commutative
fibonacci = zipWith (+) (0:1:fibonacci) (tail (0:1:fibonacci)) -- def of tail
```

Then we just define

```
fibonacci' = 0:1:fibonacci
fibonacci' = 0:1:zipWith (+) (0:1:fibonacci) (tail (0:1:fibonacci))
fibonacci' = 0:1:zipWith (+) fibonacci' (tail fibonacci')
```

which is the standard with

```
fibonacci = drop 2 fibonacci'
```

You can also use the `ParallelListComprehension` extension which lets you do zipping in list comprehensions with a slightly different syntax

```
{-# ParallelListComp #-}
fibonacci = [a + b | a <- 1:fibonacci | b <- 0:1:fibonacci]

> take 10 fibonacci
[1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89]
```

Comment: Your algebra is wrong. 0 vs. 1 issue in the last step.

Comment: It's not "wrong", it's just not equality! :) But, I should be more clear, thanks.

Comment: @Sam Glad that was useful! If you learn more about the List monad you can also desugar list comprehensions to `do`-notation to see the "non-determinism" mechanism.

Answer (score 6):

List comprehensions don't work like that. You've written a nested traversal, whereas what you are trying to do is a `zip`.

To see the difference, consider:

```
Prelude> let fibs = [ a + b | (a,b) <- zip (1 : fibs) (0 : 1 : fibs) ]
Prelude> take 10 fibs
[1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89]
```

Which works as you'd expect.

There is a syntactic extension to Haskell that allows for parallel comprehensions, so the syntax does a zip for you. You can enable it with `-XParallelListComp` and then write:

```
Prelude> let fibs = [ a + b | a <- 1 : fibs | b <- 0 : 1 : fibs ]
Prelude> take 10 fibs
[1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89]
```

Comment: Thanks! The parallel list comprehensions setting is interesting - I've not heard of it before.

Comment: But if you really want to use it, @Sam, you should actually enable it with `{-# LANGUAGE ParallelListComp #-}` at the very tippy top of the source file.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution without `zip` or `ParallelListComprehension` is:

```
> fib = 0:1:[ last x + head y | x:y:[] <- [ [take i fib, drop i fib] | i <- [1,2..] ] ]
> take 10 fib
[0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34]
```